# Почему массив изменяется

Tags: java, массивы

Доброго времени суток!

```
public class Solution {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] data = {10,1,5,124,64,12};
    System.out.println("Массив до вызова метода print: ");
    for(int ints : data) {
        System.out.print(ints + " ");
    }
    print(data);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Массив после вызова метода print: ");
    for(int ints : data){
        System.out.print(ints + " ");
    }
}
public static void print(int[] data){
    int[] arr = data;
    boolean isTrue = false;
    while(!isTrue){
        isTrue = true;
        for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
            if(arr[i-1]>arr[i]){
                int temp = arr[i-1];
                arr[i-1] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = temp;
                isTrue = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}
Вывод:
Массив до вызова метода print:
10 1 5 124 64 12
Массив после вызова метода print:
1 5 10 12 64 124

Внимание вопрос: почему массив data изменился? Я же просто вызвал метод print, в него передал мой массив. В самом методе print создал новый массив arr и работаю уже непосредственно с arr!
А по итогу массив data изменился...

Comment: Вы не создали массив а указатель на массив

Comment: Массив это ссылочный тип данных

Comment: Aziz, Массив является mutable объектом?

Comment: Да массивы mutable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Массивы это ссылочный тип данных. Существует несколько способов клонирование массивов.

```
int[] array = {23, 43, 55, 12};
int newLength = array.length;
 
int[] copiedArray = Arrays.copyOf(array, newLength);


int[] array = {23, 43, 55};
int[] copiedArray = new int[3];
 
System.arraycopy(array, 0, copiedArray, 0, 3);


int[] array = {23, 43, 55, 12};
 
int[] copiedArray = array.clone();
```

Comment: Массив является изменяемым(mutable) объектом?

Comment: Да, вы же видите что он меняется при неизменной ссылке

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь все понял! Долго голову ломал, спасибо огромное!!!

Comment: Массив, конечно, изменяемый. Если бы вы строку так передали, она бы откопировалась, и метод print ее бы не поменял.

Answer (score 0):

Метод print меняет массив, потому что он передаётся по ссылке, а не копируется. Массивы в Java передаются по ссылке.